# Не знаю как сделать оверлей

Tags: html, css

Очень простая задача сделать оверлей загнала в тупик. Мне в принципе не приходит идея, как это осуществить.

Нужно при наведении на картинку показывать оверлей с ссылкой посередине.

По наведению на `display: none` || `visibility: hidden`, `opacity: 0` - ховер просто не отрабатывает. Чрезвычайно костыльно сделал, но это нельзя назвать рабочим вариантом, т.к. он дергается и навести нужно непосредственно не на картинку, а под неё.

[Оверлей должен появляться именно с такой анимацией снизу](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oErpeW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.teaser{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:url(https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all/58e61335ec518.jpg) no-repeat center/cover;
}
.teaser__overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  opacity:0;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  transition:all .4s ease-out;
}
.teaser:hover .teaser__overlay{
  top:0;
  opacity:1;
}
.teaser__link{
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
  <div class="teaser__overlay">
    <a href="#" class="teaser__link">Перейти к галерее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pict{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.pict > img{
  display: block;  
}
.pict:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  transition: height .3s ease;
}
.pict:hover:before{
  height: 100%;
}

.pict a{
  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.pict:hover a{
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pict">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```